# Error while purchasing app ( Nokia-X InApp purchase )

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, nokiax

I am having very hard time implementing Nokia Android In-App purchase.

First issue I had faced was as follows

while testing In-App purchase with test Product-Ids you are allowed to make purchase which happens just fine.But when I try to query purchase it shows there are no purchases.Apparently I concluded that getPurchase will not work with test Ids.

Second issue I am facing is as follows.

Since getPurchases doesn't returns purchased history for Test Ids,I tried publishing one app on Nokia store with one InApp item.It got published successfully.But now when I am trying to purchase In app Item I am getting following error message.

Can somebody please help me come out of this issue?

Thanks :-)

```
03-25 12:07:16.790: I/Nokia(20913): Launching purchase flow Product.
03-25 12:07:42.910: I/Nokia(20913): onActivityResult(10001,-1,Intent { (has extras) }
03-25 12:07:42.920: I/Nokia(20913): Purchase finished: IabResult: Problem purchashing item. (response: 6:Error), purchase: null
03-25 12:07:42.920: I/Nokia(20913): Response int is 6
03-25 12:07:42.920: I/Nokia(20913): Response String is Problem purchashing item. (response: 6:Error)
03-25 12:07:42.920: I/Nokia(20913): Error purchasing: IabResult: Problem purchashing item. (response: 6:Error)
```

[image]

Comment: which SIM card you used..?

Comment: @RupeshNerkar Its Vodafone postpaid.

Answer (score 0):

In Nokia Publish portal, is your In-App Payment item state QA or Published? It can take little bit time until your item is published and only after that, you are able to use that item.

Br,
Janne

Comment: what is your product id? If that is not highest price level I can test it :)

Comment: Meanwhile, are You sure that You Are using correct is (numberic one)?

Comment: Can I have you contact id. Don't want to put product id here :)

Comment: Ok. When you have created your product in Publish portal, you get 7-digit product id like 1234567. If you want to create alias for that, you can use setProductMappings to name it like you want. In that case you need to use that alias everytime you use API. If you don't use setProductMappings, you need to use that numberic id

Comment: I am using numeric Id.I have not created any Alias.

Comment: Ok then that should not be problem. What is your operator? Maybe your operator is not supported by Nokia In-App Billing? Check http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/nokia-in-app-payment/supported-operators-for-nokia-x-software-platform.html

Comment: I am using Vodafone connection.Anyways I have published one more app with inapp purchase in Nokia Store.Will check with that ProductId and post result here :-)